# Textarea in IE when using CSS zoom

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, textarea, zooming

I've come across a bit of an oddity in IE, surprise surprise ;) It seems IE gets a bit confused when CSS zoom is applied to a textarea. When using some zoomlevels the text carret gets "stuck" on some lines and its not possible to go to the line above, however using the mouse still works. I made a simple example to illustrate the problem. In the example the carret gets stuck on the last line (Testing5), however changing the zoom level to 78% the carret will now get stuck on the second to last (Testing4) line.

Example code:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <STYLE>.textboxML { ZOOM: 75%; }</STYLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <FORM>
      <TEXTAREA rows="8" class="textboxML" rows=8 cols=15>Testing1
Testing2
Testing3
Testing4
Testing5</TEXTAREA>
    </FORM>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Same on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y55v5/

Anyone seen this one before?

Cheers,

Michael

Comment: Congrats, you found a bug in Internet Explorer! Didn't see it before, but not surprised a bit. As workaround you might better change font size, don't work with the buggy zoom.

Comment: Any special reason you are using `zoom` in the first place considering it's IE only? Which IE version are you using/supporting? Have you tried [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform](`transform`) (suppoered by all modern browsers, however IE only from 9 onward).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys :) I would'nt mind limiting to IE9 and onward, however it seems that transform uses the same buggy calculation method as that of zoom. When replacing zoom: 75% with {-ms-transform: scale(0.5,0.5) I see a similar situation as the zoom one :(